# Error trying to add +1 second of sleep for a retry

Tags: python

In this example I try to activate `main()` again in case there is an error in `one()`:

```
from random import randrange
import sys
import time

def one():
    number = randrange(2)
    1/number

def main():
    try:
        one()
    except:
        sleep_time = 0
        while True:
            print('Error')
            sleep_time += 1
            print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time) + ' second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            main()
            sys.exit(1)

    print('Continue')

main()
```

When two errors occur in a row, it keeps giving a 1 second pause:

```
Error
Next attempt in: 1 second(s)
Error
Next attempt in: 1 second(s)
Continue
```

What I'm actually looking for would be an answer like this:

```
Error
Next attempt in: 1 second(s)
Error
Next attempt in: 2 second(s)
Continue
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You are overwriting `sleep_time` back to `sleep_time = 0` with every iteration.

Comment: You're setting `sleep_time=0` inside the except block. With your implementation you need to pass it as an argument to main() or make it a global variable. Or, use something like the [retry](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) package

Comment: Obligatory warning: Never use bare `except`. **Always** catch the specific error you expect (like `ZeroDivisionError` in this case).

Comment: Hi @TedKleinBergman , I put this division error only as an example, because in fact the error comes from a ```request()``` that exceeds the ```timeout``` of 5 seconds.

Comment: @BrondbyIF All answers/questions needs such a warning in the comment section either way because people who read the question/answers will just blindly copy it with the justification "I found it on Stackoverflow", unfortunately.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I understand and fully agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `sleep_time` back to zero with every recursive call to `main` Assign it as a param of the function

```
def main(sleep_time=0):
    try:
        one()
    except:
        while True:
            print('Error')
            sleep_time += 1
            print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time) + ' second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            main(sleep_time=sleep_time)
            sys.exit(1)

    print('Continue')
```

out

```
Error
Next attempt in: 1 second(s)
Error
Next attempt in: 2 second(s)
Error
Next attempt in: 3 second(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was also identified in the other answers.
An alternative solution, probably less "beautiful" than Frederick's is to pass the variable `sleep_time` as input to the main function:

```py
from random import randrange
import sys
import time

def one():
    number = randrange(2)
    1/number

def main(sleep_time):
    try:
        one()
    except:
        
        while True:
            print('Error')
            sleep_time += 1
            print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time) + ' second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
            main(sleep_time)
            sys.exit(1)

    print('Continue')

main(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you always call the main function again and *reset* `sleep_time` to `0` and then `add 1` again. Its working without calling it again:

```
from random import randrange
import sys
import time

def one():
    number = randrange(2)
    1/number

def main():
    try:
        one()
    except:
        sleep_time = 0
        while True:
            print('Error')
            sleep_time += 1
            print('Next attempt in: '+ str(sleep_time) + ' second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

    print('Continue')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `try` inside `while` would make your code way easier to read and probably eliminates to need to call `main()` over and over again:

```
import sys
import time


def one():
    raise ValueError("Error!")


def main():
    sleep_time = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            one()
        except:
            sleep_time += 1
            print(f'Next attempt in: {sleep_time} second(s)')
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
        else:
            print("Ok. Exit here")
            sys.exit(0)

main()
```

Out:

```
Next attempt in: 1 second(s)
Next attempt in: 2 second(s)
Next attempt in: 3 second(s)
...
```